# I need values from one data frame to another data frame in python pandas based on column name

Tags: python, dataframe

Example
df1

```
Abc   Def  GHI  JKL
a     23    e    h
b     24    g    h
c     27    h    k
d     34    f    j
```

df2

```
Abc   XYZ  
a     23   
b     24   
c     27   
d     34   
e     54    
f     32    
g     21
```

I need output like this

```
Abc   Def  GHI  JKL   XYZ
a     23    e    h     23
b     24    g    h     24
c     27    h    k     27
d     34    f    j     34
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.merge
out = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='Def', right_on='Xyz')
          .reindex(columns=['Abc', 'Def', 'Ghi', 'Jkl' , 'Xyz']))
print(out)
```